# how to determine if a json_decode contains a deep value in php

Tags: php, json

I've been searching and can't find an exact duplicate. Although there are many related questions on OS they don't tell me what I'm looking for exactly.

I'm a c coder not a php coder, so I'm just faking my way through as my php guy isn't available.  I have server software that checks an in app purchase receipt from apple and does stuff with the results, including putting them in a table on my server database.

```
$endpoint="https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt";
$response=$objDB->verifyreceiptProcess($endpoint,$postData);
// parse the response data
$data1 = json_decode($response);  //  Response of sandbox

if( $data1->status == 0){  //  Sandbox Status =0
   $insertPurchase[0]["Field"]="user_id";
   $insertPurchase[0]["Value"]=$params['user_id'];
   $insertPurchase[1]["Field"]="product_id";
   $insertPurchase[1]["Value"]=$data1->receipt->product_id;
   $insertPurchase[2]["Field"]="receiptData";
   $insertPurchase[2]["Value"]=substr($params['receipt'],0,50);
   $insertPurchase[3]["Field"]="game_title";
   $insertPurchase[3]["Value"]=$params['game_id'];
   $insertPurchase[4]["Field"]="date_of_purchasing";
   $insertPurchase[4]["Value"]=$data1->receipt->purchase_date;
   $insertPurchase[5]["Field"]="apple_transaction_id";
   $insertPurchase[5]["Value"]=$data1->receipt->transaction_id; 
   $insertPurchase[6]["Field"]="app_item_id";
   $insertPurchase[6]["Value"]=$data1->receipt->app_item_id;
   ....
```

Then later it query_inserts this into my table to record the purchase, and returns info back to my app.

The problem is that right now the field **app_item_id** isn't there.  My guess is that until the app is submitted this field isn't returned.  This causes my server software to just return "false".  If I call the api from safari, the word "false" prints instead of the formatted json result.

So I need to error check this last line up there to make sure that field is there before sticking it in $insertPurchase[6]["Value"] and if not put "" in there.

I assume isset can be used but don't understand how to use it to detect something this deep in a json result.

Sorry if this question is too basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
if(isset($data1->receipt->app_item_id))
{
    $insertPurchase[6]["Value"]=$data1->receipt->app_item_id;
} else {
     $insertPurchase[6]["Value"]="";
}
```